# Mac firewall or tool that blocks access to websites based on geographic location?

Tags: gratis, security, web, firewall

I'm looking for a free Mac OS firewall that allows blocking of sites based on the server's estimated geographic location or iptable-like banning at a minimum.

The main application is to thwart typosquatting and phishing attacks which often originate in Russia, China, and eastern Europe.

From what I read, perfect geoblocking is extremely difficult due to the number of IP ranges that have to be covered. For all practical purposes, a tool that blocks access to >= 95% of sites in given geographic locations should be sufficient.